# Can I use a "UseEffect" only with a certain value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am trying to use a UseEffect of react hooks, I know I can add variables that on change can activate it, but I would like to know if there is a way to activate the useEffect only when the value meets certain criteria.

I have already created a conditional inside the useEffect and I know it works, but I would like to know if there's another way to do it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  doSomething();
  if(!isOpen)
   doSomething2();
}, [isOpen, otherThing]);
```

In the example above I want doSomething2 to work only when its value is false.

isOpen in this examample has a default value of false, then when it retrieves something from the database it turns into true and finally when it finished fetching it goes back to false.

I expect the hook to activate only when the value switches from true to false and not in every change.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

No other way. Your attempt is already correct. That's the only way. Cheers!

`useEffect()` only allows dependencies and no conditional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple data that can be changed like this.

```js
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = React.useState(null);
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = React.useState({});
```

if you want to get an event for a specific attribute like `restaurants`
then you can use one `useEffect` method for that. and for the other one, you can use another `useEffect` method like below.

```
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = React.useState(null);
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = React.useState(restaurantData);

useEffect(() => {
   console.log("this is for selectedCategory")
}, [selectedCategory]);

useEffect(() => {
   console.log("this is for restaurants")
}, [restaurants]);
```

Thanks.